# Exception Handling Python3

Tags: python-3.x, exception, typeerror

I'm practicing exception handling and when I try to execute the following code, python doesn't handle the TypeError exception if i enter a text instead of number. Following is the code :

```
num1=input("Enter the first number : ")
num2=input("Enter the second number : ")
try:
    num1=int(num1)
    num2=int(num2)
except TypeError:
    print("Sorry, that wasn't a number, please try again")
else:
    print(add)
```

Comment: It raises a `ValueError`, not a `TypeError`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not tracking the correct error:

```
>>> int("not a number")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'not a number'
```

ValueError is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, now it worked. Why do we use TypeError then?

Comment: Quoting from https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html. `TypeError` -  Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch. Try typing '2' + 2 in python CLI.

Comment: @KushagraChughੴ: `input()` always returns a string, and `int()` takes a string object as argument. If you were to pass something in that *was not a string* (and not any of the other accepted types) you'd get a `TypeError`, e.g. `int(None)`. But since you always pass in a string, that's not the case here.